# Can sandbox purchases from Flutter app be ignored on Firebase Analytics?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-analytics, in-app-purchase

I have built a Flutter app for iOS that has an auto-renewing subscription in-app-purchase. I am using Flutter's [`in_app_purchase`](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_purchase) package for the purchases and Firebase for much of the backend, including analytics. I haven't written any custom analytics for IAP.

The revenue analytics shows a bunch of money in the "Total Revenue" graph, though no money in the ecommerce or ad lines. Opening these data in Google Analytics there's an option to view in app purchases, but there are none there, either.

This "revenue" is coming from the sandbox purchases my beta testers have made. Is there any way to ignore sandbox purchases in analytics? Has anyone else run into a similar problem?

Comment: You can add flavors in app,you may have one build for development & another for production. Then turn off analytics for developer build.Hopefully that will work. this package can help https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_flavor

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem doesn't belong to Flutter, but to Google Analytics.
Therefore, I would create a custom rule to filter specific events inside Google Analytics.

Here are some links that might help you:

[GA4 - Filter Events](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10104470?hl=en)

[Analytics Academy](https://analytics.google.com/analytics/academy/)